# Independant varible value in one-sided limits

Tags: calculus, limits

The book I'm reading describes this concept very poorly. When evaluating a function $\lim_{x \to 0^+}\ f(x)$ what would x approach to when evaluating said function? What would $\lim_{x \to 0^-}$ be?

And on a not completely unrelated note, when would a function approach to $\infty$. When $-\infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to second question:

A function cannot "equal" infinity. It is a concept, not a number. But in this weird theoretical situation, when a function *approaches* infinity, its limit as x approaches zero of infinity, would be infinity. The function wouldn't be dependent on x. Same thing for negative infinity.

Edit: This function has a vertical asymptote at the value x = 0, x = 1, and x = 2.

One sided limits are a lot less "algebra-y" in that you can't plug in a formula and find the answer. You have to think.

The best way to start is to find what is happening at the vertical asymptotes.

What happens when x is positive but really, really small? Well, you end up getting two negative numbers for (x-1) and (x-2), so what we have will be equal to 1 divided by (positive infitesimal)(negative number)(negative number), or 1 divided by (positive super duper small). You don't have to determine their values because the infitesimal just makes everything super duper small. When you divide 1 by a really small number, you get a huge number. Therefore, when x is super small and positive, you get 1/(positive super small). We can visualize this as

$
\frac{1}{0.0000000000000000000000000001}
$.

If you evaluate something like this in your calculator, chances are you get a super huge number. Every time the number gets smaller, the result gets larger. So, if x is infinitely small but positive, the result is $\infty$.

For a negative but really small x, we have 1 / (negative super small)(negative super small)(negative super small), or 1 / (negative infinitesimal) or to use our epic visualization,

$
\frac{1}{-0.0000000000000000000000000001}
$, or 
$
\frac{-1}{0.0000000000000000000000000001}
$. Now you probably get some super huge negative value, and as the denominator gets smaller, the result keeps becoming a larger and larger negative number. Therefore, when the denominator is infinitely small, the result is $-\infty$.

Comment: zero of infinity? What do you mean?

Comment: Think about this. The limit as x approaches 0 for f(x) = 4 is 4, right? From both the positive and negative sides, f(x) approaches 4. Same thing for f(x) = infinity. No matter what f(x) is, the answer is infinity. So f(0) is infinity.

Similarly, if f(x) = - infinity, f(0) = - infinity.

Comment: Do you mean four? Rather than for?

Comment: 4 was an arbitrary number. Let's say f(x) = 1000. f(4) = 1000. f($\pi$) = 1000. f($\sin(42)$) = 1000. So no matter what f(x) is, the answer is 1000. We can describe this as a function independent of x, because no matter what x is, the answer is still the same. With f(x)= infinity, no matter what x is, the answer is infinity. Therefore, if x = 0, the answer should still be infinity. This is an independent function.

Bit of confusing concept. HMU if further help required.

Comment: In the function I'm asked to evaluate($f(x) = \frac {1}{x(x-1)(x-2)}$), the answer seems to be affected by the limit being approached from left or right. At 0, if approached from the negative side, the function approaches $-\infty$ while for the opposite it approaches $\infty$. Can you help explain?

Comment: have to use an answer, because not enough characters in a comment

Comment: You can edit you previous answer, if you don't have enough space.

Comment: Thanks, it is so much clearer now!